# В какую сторону думать, чтоб создать графическую полоску рейтинга?

Tags: php, mysql

Как делать рейтинг я знаю. Что-нибудь типа несколько звёздочек, и несколько картинок с увеличением раскрашенных звёздочек на одну - тоже не подходит. К примеру вконтакте так как надо рейтинг оформлен(который под аватаром). Если посмотреть в код, то это класс css. Полоска увеличивалась если отправить смс для повышения рейтинга. Вот меня и интересует, как эта полоска увеличивалась. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: @Кирилл Романтик, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Полоску можно увеличивать стилями

```
<div id="rate">
    <div class="line">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

css

```
#rate{width: 200px; }
#rate .line {background-color: #F4A460;}
```

Т.е. есть блок для рейтинга, внутри есть полоска, которая будет заполняться в процентах.
Например, если рейтиг составляет 123 при максимальных 500, то получится так:

```
$rate = 123;
$max = 500;
```

В верстке:

```
...
<div class="line" style="width: <?= (($rate * 100) / $max) ?>%">&nbsp;</div>
```